# Indian resident owning dividend-paying shares in company based in France: Can I save on withholding tax?

Tags: taxes, india, dividends, withholding, france

I am Indian and staying in India. I am holding stocks/shares of a French company which is listed on the Paris stock exchange.

Every year, the French company declares dividend on the shares, and on those dividends 30% tax is getting deducted and withheld. How can save on this tax, as the dividend is reduced by it, and I don't stay in France. Also, how can I get tax back which was deducted on the dividends?

Comment: The `30% tax` is withheld by your broker, I believe. You can reclaim the paid tax(under the tax treaty between India and France), check with an accountant while filing your tax returns.

Answer (score 1):

France taxes capital / dividend gains accrued in France. Hence you will not be able to reduce this liability. India does have a [Double Tax Avoidance Treaty with France](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/Pages/international-taxation/dtaa.aspx) and you can claim relief for the tax paid in France.